# Swing graphics reposition drawString

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am drawing a string on the users screen, and I want to move that string around, but it doesn't change position, This is my code

```
public static int x = 200, y = 200;

    public static Window draw() {
    Window w = new Window(null) {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            System.out.println("repainting");
            final Font font = getFont().deriveFont(48f);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            final String message = "Hello";
            FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
            g.drawString(message, x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paint(g);
        }
    };
    w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    w.setBounds(w.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
    w.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
    w.setVisible(true);
    return w;
}


  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Window window = draw();
        x = 500;
        y = 500;
        window.repaint();
        window.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

It doesn't seem to change the text position, It prints out `repainting` so the point method is getting called, and I have printed `x, y` inside the paint method and it seems to be updated aswell, so there is something wrong with graphics that doesn't want to draw a new string.

Comment: This is horrible. Why are you overriding 'update'? What is Window, is that an AWT Window? Why do you override paint? You should make a component that you add to your window, and over ride the paintComponent. On top of that you never change x/y so how would the string move around?

Comment: @matt, I change the x, y in my original code, There is a `while` loop changing the x, y. I am trying to draw a string on the screen, so I created an empty ` java.awt.Window` and updated the paint method to draw a String.

Comment: x, y is a global variable. Forgot to include in the question, updated.

Comment: *"Forgot to include in the question"* Forget adding bits'n'pieces of uncompilable code. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete your Window class altogether and replace it with a JFrame. Then the custom class should be a JPanel and just override the paintComponent. I am guessing it doesn't work so you're going through things to make it work and you've ended up with some pretty dodgy code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Confusion{
    static int x = 100;
    static int y = 0;
    static double theta = 0;

    public static void startGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                g.drawString("string", x, y);
            }
        };
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer( 30, (e)->{
            x = (int)(300 + Math.sin(theta)*200);
            y = (int)(300 - Math.cos(theta)*200);
            theta += 0.1;
            panel.repaint();        
        } );
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait( Confusion::startGui );   
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to draw another string, instead of changing the position of the original one.

Comment: *"This seems to draw another string.."* The `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g);` to erase previous drawings.

Comment: Now I look at the code in the answer more closely, two additional points. 1) Java Swing / AWT GUIs should be constructed and updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). 2) Animation would normally be done using a Swing `Timer`, which ensures any updates to the GUI are done on the EDT.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree with point 1, and I can add that. I was mainly trying to point in a direction of actually using swing classes instead of awt, and overriding the appropriate methods. Point 2 I find depends on the animation step. In this simple example I would agree with you. Ill make an update for completeness.